# What would "$a$" be in this scenario?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I was given the following description for a problem, and I'm uncertain on what $a$ is meant to represent

> Let $S(n)$ be the sum of all positive integers $m$ not exceeding $n$ having the following property:
>
> > $a^{m+4} ≡ a \pmod m$ for all integers $a$.

Comment: that congruence statement is true for all integers $a$. So fix $n$, then fix $m$, then if that statement is true you add $m$ to $S(n)$. You do this for all $m$ smaller than the fixed $n$.

Comment: @aboat I'm aware of that, but is $a$ meant to represent integers under $n$? Or from 0 to infinity?

Comment: What do you mean by integers under $n$? It means that for any $a$ that you'd pick from the set of natural numbers that statement holds. There is no limit here.

Comment: @aboat oh, ok. Thank you.

Comment: No, the statement does not say that. In concordance with that statement, $a$ can be any natural number.

Comment: "All integers" includes negative integers. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

First you ask whether $1$ contributes to your sum.  For that to happen, you need $a^5 \equiv a \pmod 1$ for all integers $a$.  Since anything $\pmod 1$ is zero, this is true and $1$ will be part of $S(n)$ for any $n \ge 1$.  Now you know $S(1)=1$.  Then you ask whether $2$ contributes.  For that to happen, you need $a^6 \equiv a \pmod 2$ for all integers $a$.  This is true because the sixth power of an even number is even, and the sixth power of an odd number is odd.  This tells you $S(2)=3$.  Now try a few more and see if you can find a pattern.